# Solving complex equations

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I feel like I am missing a basic, but key point when using Mathematica's `Solve` or `Reduce`.

```
Assuming[Element[{a, b, zr, zi}, Reals],
  Solve[a + I b == zr + I zi, zi]
]
```

reduces to

```
{{zi -> b + I (-a + zr)}}
```

I can't really phrase the question better, but I was expecting `zi -> b`.

Along the same lines, how do I get `Solve[a + I b == z, b]` to return `b -> Im[z]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, the reason why this doesn't work is that `Solve` and `Reduce` do not have an `Assumptions` option, so `Assuming` has no effect on them.

#### Using `Reduce`

We can tell `Reduce` that these variables are all real-valued like this:

```
Reduce[a + I b == zr + I zi && Element[{a, b, zr, zi}, Reals], zi]

(* ==> (zr | b) \[Element] Reals && a == zr && zi == b *)
```

#### Using `Solve`

There's a note in the documentation:

> `Solve[expr && vars \[Element] Reals, vars, Complexes]` solves for real values
>   of variables, but function values are allowed to be complex.

However, `Solve[a + I b == zr + I zi && (a | b | zr | zi) \[Element] Reals, zi, Complexes]` returns `{}` which means that there are no solutions.  Why does this happen?  `zi` has a real value only if `a == zr`, so *in general* (for arbitrary `a`, `zr` values) there is no *real* solution for `zi`.  The main difference between `Reduce` and `Solve` is that `Reduce` will try to generate those specific conditions under which a solution exists while `Solve` does not.

---

#### Why doesn't `Assuming` work?

Generally, `Assuming` works by setting `$Assumptions` temporarily:

```
In[1]:= $Assumptions
Out[1]= True

In[2]:= Assuming[x > 0, $Assumptions]
Out[2]= x > 0
```

It will have an effect on functions that have an `Assumptions` option.  These functions have `Assumptions -> $Assumptions` as a default setting:

```
In[3]:= Options[Integrate]
Out[3]= {Assumptions :> $Assumptions, GenerateConditions -> Automatic,
  PrincipalValue -> False}

In[4]:= Options[Simplify]
Out[4]= {Assumptions :> $Assumptions, ComplexityFunction -> Automatic,
  ExcludedForms -> {}, TimeConstraint -> 300, 
 TransformationFunctions -> Automatic, Trig -> True}
```

It will not have an effect on functions that do not have this option:

```
In[5]:= Options[Solve]
Out[5]= {Cubics -> True, GeneratedParameters -> C, 
 InverseFunctions -> Automatic, MaxExtraConditions -> 0, 
 Method -> Automatic, Modulus -> 0, Quartics -> True, 
 VerifySolutions -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> \[Infinity]}

In[6]:= Options[Reduce]
Out[6]= {Backsubstitution -> False, Cubics -> False, 
 GeneratedParameters -> C, Method -> Automatic, Modulus -> 0, 
 Quartics -> False, WorkingPrecision -> \[Infinity]}
```

I could imagine though that `Solve` or `Reduce` make internal use of some function that does take `$Assumptions` into account.  I do not know if this is the case or not, but I doubt that generally `$Assumptions` would have an effect on them.

Comment: Not all functions with `Assumtion` Option do have the default `Assumptions->$Assumptions`. AFAIK the only one which doesn't is `PowerExpand` with default `Assumptions->True`. So `Assuming` works only for Functions having the default option `Assumptions->$Assumptions`.

Comment: @PeterBreitfeld Thanks for pointing that out!  I checked the docs and they say:  "You can specify default assumptions for PowerExpand using Assuming."  It doesn't work though unless  I use `Assumptions -> $Assumptions`.

Comment: I think WRI has thougt about the Assumptions option of PowerExoand. I wrote the default were True, but it is Automatic. Look what `Power[(a b)^n,Assumptions->#]&/@{Automatic,True}` does. `$Assumptions` defaults to `True`, so `Assumptions->$Assumptions` is not appropriate for `PowerExpand`

Answer (score 4):

If you have equations with only real variables, then I found it's best to split them in a list of Real and Imaginary Parts:

```
reImToList[expr_] := (ComplexExpand[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ ComplexExpand[expr]])
```

Then for the OP question:

```
eq=a + I b == zr + I zi
Solve[reImToList[eq], {zi, zr}]

(* {{zi -> b, zr -> a}} *)
```

This works for more complicated cases as well, e.g. the following will not give the desired result:

```
gl = a + b I == 1/(c + d I)
Solve[gl, {c, d}]
ComplexExpand[gl]
Solve[%, {c, d}]
```

But splitting will work easily:

```
reImToList[gl];
Solve[%, {c, d}]

(* {{c -> a/(a^2 + b^2), d -> -(b/(a^2 + b^2))}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

For both expamples `ComplexExpand`  gives the desired result:

```
Solve[ComplexExpand[Im[#]] & /@ (a + I b == zr + I zi)]
```

> {{b->zi}}

```
Solve[ComplexExpand[Im[#], z] & /@ (a + I b == z)]
```

> {{b->Im(z)}}

**Edit**

Well, here's a more complicated variant for the case then all parameters are real.
In particular for `a` and `b` from your example. Constants in the equation should not be floating point numbers and `E`. If you need `E` in equaion it could be changed to some other not used transcendent constant like `EulerGamma`. Floating point numbers can be included with `Rationalize`.

```
var = a;
params = {b, zr, zi};
eqn = a + I b == (zr + I Sqrt[3] zi)^-2;
rules = Table[params[[k]] -> E^\[Pi]^k, {k, Length[params]}];
Re[var /. Solve[{eqn /. rules}, var]] /. 
E^Plus[a$__] :> Times @@ (a$ /. k$_. \[Pi]^l$_. :> params[[l$]]^k$) // Simplify
```

> {(zr - 3*zi)/(2*(3*zi + zr)^2)}

Comment: But this implies apriori knowledge of the solution - if I wanted to solve for `a` instead, I'd have to rewrite it.

Answer (score 2):

You may like more to use `Reduce` in this case. Try this:

```
Reduce[a + I b == zr + I zi && Element[{a, b, zr, zi}, Reals], b]

(zr | zi) \[Element] Reals && a == zr && b == zi
```