# Solve equations real and imaginary part separately

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, complex

For my system of equations, the procedure described in [Solving complex equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5314/solving-complex-equations) of using `Reduce` works no more. How can I separate the real and imaginary part of the equations? Because then I could use `Solve[equations, vars, Reals]`. Nevertheless I hope for a simpler way to overcome this issue.

**Example**

```
Vector = {v1, v2, v3, v4};
Matrix = {{c11, c12, c13, c14}, 
          {c21, c22, c23, c24}, 
          {c31, c32, c33, c34}, 
          {c41, c42, c43, c44}};
Reduce[Table[0 == Sum[Matrix[[r, k]] Vector[[k]], {k, 4}], {r, 4}] && 
 Element[{v1Real, v1Complex, v2Real, v2Complex, v3Real, v3Complex, v4Real, v4Complex}, Reals],
 {v1Real, v1Complex, v2Real, v2Complex, v3Real, v3Complex, v4Real, v4Complex}] /. 
 {v1 -> v1Real + I v1Complex, v2 -> v2Real + I v2Complex, v3 -> v3Real + I v3Complex, v4 -> v4Real + I v4Complex}
```

Comment: We could likely provide something more useful to you if on;y you'd explicitly mention what your "system of equations" are.

Comment: The way you defined the equations you can only expect trivial solutions. Try to check `eq = (# == 0) & /@ (matrix . vector);Solve[eq, vector, Complexes]`. Also be careful with the fact that initiating symbols with capital letters are avoided in Mathematica.

Comment: I want to introduce some symmetry properties into the vector as in my case the vector represents the density matrix, i.e. Complexes is no intuitive option!

Comment: It's a linear system. You can use LinearSolve. Then, if you must, separate the symbolic solution into real and imaginary parts using `Re` and `Im`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) mentions in [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24513/solve-equations-real-and-imaginary-part-separately#comment75998_24513):

> It's a linear system. You can use `LinearSolve`. Then, if you must, separate the symbolic solution into real and imaginary parts using `Re` and `Im`.

Comment: If you want to get credit for this answer, could you please write out the corresponding code? ;) Thank you!

Comment: I am not looking for credit; I only posted this to get the question off the unanswered list, and the answer is already marked as "community wiki", which means no points accrue to the poster. Is it really helpful for you if I add "`Through@{Re, Im}@LinearSolve[Matrix, Vector]`" to the above or was the comment clear enough already? I think probably the latter.

Comment: I agree with you since I did not want to bother you.

Comment: @strpeter if this answer doesn't meet your needs then please clarify the question and perhaps you can get a better one. There is nothing wrong with saying that an answer doesn't help, if that's the case--it just seemed to me that Daniel's comment was all that was needed to address it, but maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: It perfectly solves the question. I am not using Mathematica often enough - so I did not get it and forgot to ask back. Just a final last question: What is the `@` operator, i.e. `Prefix[]` function in this case doing exactly?

Comment: @strpeter good--glad to hear that it is a useful answer. To write it out without using `@`, we have `Through[{Re, Im}[LinearSolve[Matrix, Vector]]]`. The `@` is right-associative and simply takes the place of the function application brackets. I usually write `Through` this way as I find it easier to read than the infix form.